# Proper way to link against libraries with dependencies?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, frameworks, dylib

I'm working on a fairly simple OS X app that uses a couple third-party libraries (SoX and TwoLAME) to do some audio converting. TwoLAME relies on libsndfile, and SoX relies on sndfile plus a number of other libraries.

For development, I simply installed the two libraries with Homebrew, which took care of the dependencies, and then linked right to them (ie in /usr/local/Cellar/...). Now that I'm ready to deploy, I need to figure out a way to get everything packaged up.

I know frameworks are a bit ambiguous in Cocoa (fake ones, dynamic ones, etc), but it seems like ideally I would end up with some frameworks of one kind or another that I can drop into the project and everything would work.

I've read through a *lot* of different docs and tutorials about frameworks, and tried a number of approaches, but I seem to be missing some core concept for getting this all to work together.

I have been able to make frameworks from the libraries that sort of work, in the sense that I compile from source, take the static (.a) library and put it in a "fake" framework with the headers, and the app will run with those. Those static libraries are still referencing the dependencies on my local path, though. So, eg, if I uninstall Lame from Homebrew, the SoX static library in my framework will fail.

I'm really struggling to figure out what the best way **cleanly** get all these libraries and their dependencies into this app. The tutorials I've seen about building dynamic Cocoa libraries from scratch have been very hard to do with the source code for these pre-existing libraries. The other option I have considered it build dylibs and then use `install_name_tool` to change paths to be relative just ship everything with the app and try to match everything up.

There's got to be some better way that I'm just missing, and would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Did you finally compiled the libraries on your own? I don't think you can copy the files from homebrew, because they are compiled with the prefix. What works for me: I download the source, configure without prefix, compile and than I move the .a files and the .h files to my project (you don't have to create a .framework)

Comment: Ultimately I realized that most of what I was asking here was unnecessary. TwoLAME actually *didn't* have a libsndfile dependency when building only the library, and I was able to switch from sox to soxr which had what I was using in sox without the dependencies. So all I had to do was build static libraries of each library like you said. I did package them as .frameworks just for easier distribution.